# How to allow the trustor(account) to trust the asset I created

Tags: assets, stellar-sdk, testnet

I want to make a account (public key) to trust a asset I issue myself.

When I run an allowTrust operation, snippet below, I get `op_no_trustline` error :

```
                const issuingAccount = await this.stellarServer.loadAccount(issuerKeys.publicKey())
                const transaction = new TransactionBuilder(issuingAccount, {
                    fee: BASE_FEE,
                    networkPassphrase: Networks.TESTNET
                })
                .addOperation(Operation.allowTrust({
                    trustor,
                    assetCode,
                    authorize: true
                }))
                .setTimeout(0)
                .build()
                transaction.sign(issuerKeys)
                const result = await this.stellarServer.submitTransaction(transaction)
```

I don't know why I get this error, since I want to allow the trustor(account) to trust the asset I created?

I have set this   `setFlags: AuthRevocableFlag | AuthRequiredFlag` to the issue account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trustor needs to first create a trustline in any case.

Since your asset is "AuthRequired" they will create an unauthorized trustline first (which could be also seen as a kind of authorization request) using the `changeTrust` operation, you can authorize/approve that trustline only if it exists in the first place.